# How to show message after filter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

After selecting Filter,I want to show summary tab/message what we selected.
I googled it and found session method, is it suitable in my case?
Here is my blade

```html
   {!! Form::open(['url'=>'/jobseekers','method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'form', 'id'=>'search_data']) !!}

              <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" value="{{ request()->input('fullname')}}" class="form-control"/>
              </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="fb_name" placeholder="Fb Name" value="{{ request()->input('fb_name')}}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                          <button class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Search</button>
              </div>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and in my controller

```html
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $result = null;
        if(count($request->all())!=0){  
            if ($request->has('sub_search')) {
                $jobseekers = Jobseeker::Subsearch($request)->paginate(10); 
                dd($applicant_information);

            }else{
                $result=Jobseeker::Search($request)->paginate(10);  
              //  dd($orders);
            } 

        }
        else{
     
            $jobseekers = Jobseeker::with('calllogs')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(16);
        }       


       return view('backend.jobseekers.index',compact('jobseekers','result')); 
    }
```

I am using get method to filter,and i want to show like

> The Search results for **fullname** and **fb_name** are:

Is there any way to do like that in my case? Please guide me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to display filtered result in view? If so, change your code to:-

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $fullname = $request->fullname;
        $fb_name= $request->fb_name;
        $result = null;
        if(count($request->all())!=0){  
            if ($request->has('sub_search')) {
                $jobseekers = Jobseeker::Subsearch($request)->paginate(10); 
                dd($applicant_information);

            }else{
                $result=Jobseeker::Search($request)->paginate(10);  
              //  dd($orders);
            } 

        }
        else{

            $jobseekers = Jobseeker::with('calllogs')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(16);
        }       


       return view('backend.jobseekers.index',compact('jobseekers','result'))->with('fullname',$fullname)->with('fb_name',$fb_name); 
    }
```

All you need to is to access the passed variable from this controller is like

The Search results for {{$fullname}} and {{$fb_name}} are:

and loop your result here...